# Backgroundworker stops (unwanted) in middle of sub

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I apologize in advance if I happened to look past an answer for my situation.

I am using a background worker to execute some code in the background.  This is the first time I've used a background worker and I am getting inconsistent results from it.

Using breakpoints, I have been able to find where the background worker ceases to stop working.

The line is:

```
RDFValues(I) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

The line works perfectly if I run it in the main thread, but it seems to stop the background worker in its tracks.

My question is why would this line cause a background worker to stop, but not the main thread?

I suspect it has something to do with a thread race, but I'm not completely sure.  I even added a `Synclock` to the code block that calls the sub with this line, so I'm at a loss.

If anyone could help me out I would be greatly appreciative.  :)

I should also note that the sub being called exists in a module outside of where the backgroundworker is working.

Comment: What is `RDFValues`? is it databound to, or part of a UI control?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that too.  RFDValues is a variable in the sub being called.

Comment: Is it bound to the UI at all? When your code stops - is it deadlocked, or is it throwing an exception? (if so, what exception?)

Comment: Sorry, I edited my last comment.  I was wrong.  It's not global it's specific to the sub.  It is not databound and no exceptions are being thrown.  The BW just stops working.  :(  I'm not sure what you mean deadlocked other than that the UI is unresponsive.  If so, then no it is not deadlocked.  The program still works fine.

Comment: Sorry forgot to say it's not part of a UI control.

Comment: Any changes of showing a bit more from the code, including how you initiate it and such? What about the `SyncLock`? Did you check the `RunWorkerCompleted` event? Are any errors mentioned there?

Comment: I just ran the code again.  I originally wasn't collecting the error from the RunWorkerCompleted.  I just did that and I got an exception.  :)

Comment: It's coming back with Null or With block not set, so now I have an idea of where to start.  :)  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I figured I'd mention that I solved the problem.  It turned out that it wasn't the line I mentioned initially that was causing the issue.  It was the preceding line which was trying to reference the UI's binding source.  So I guess it's safe to assume that backgroundworkers don't mesh well with the Main Thread.  :)

Comment: To anyone reading this who is as much of a noob as I am, here's what I did to get past my problem.

I was using bindingsources from my UI to fill some variables (which is why the sub worked when running on the Main Thread)

I ended up having to ditch using the BS and use a programmatic approach.

I created a function which returned a DataTable and then used a DataRow object to filter the results.

This worked and my background worker accomplishes it's task without error now.  :)

Good luck to the rest of you noobs!  :)

Comment: @Crimson531 can you please answer your own question and mark it as answered so it won't stay in the unanswered questions ;)

Comment: Oh!! Sorry I'm such a noob!  :)  Will do!

Comment: @DavidSdot It says I can accept my answer in 2 days.  :(  So I can't do that right now

Comment: :) no prob, good luck with your bgw ;)

Comment: Thank you!  I have actually made leaps and bounds, but unfortunately I had to retailor my code to make them work correctly.  Sometimes you have to learn things the hard way.  :)  Thank you for the support again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone reading this who is as much of a noob as I am, here's what I did to get past my problem. I was using bindingsources from my UI to fill some variables (which is why the sub worked when running on the Main Thread) I ended up having to ditch using the BS and use a programmatic approach. I created a function which returned a DataTable and then used a DataRow object to filter the results. This worked and my background worker accomplishes it's task without error now. :) Good luck to the rest of you noobs! :)